How can I select a value from one dataframe based on two other values in another dataframe
From the following two dataframes, I want to substitute all data$code columns with the corresponding code$atc_code. To do this, the data$name value should correspond with code$med_name, and the data$code value should correspond with code$first_code (as some names have several codes).
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6),
            name1 = c('Triamcinolonacetonide', 'Triamcinolonacetonide', 'nifedipine', 'Nystatine', 'Ethinylestradiol/​levonorgestrel', "Nystatine"),
           quantity1 = c(10, 10, 15, 30, 20, 10),
           dose1 = c(5, 5, 15, 0.5, 2, 10), 
           code1 = c('D', 'S', 'C', 'A', 'G', "A"),
          name2 = c('Pantoprazol', 'levothyroxine', 'Fusidinezuur', 'Ethinylestradiol/​levonorgestrel', 'Nystatine', "Nystatine"),
           quantity2 = c(5, 10, 10, 20, 20, 5),
           dose2 = c(0.1, 15, 15, 7, 5, 12), 
           code2 = c('A', 'H', 'D', 'G', 'A', "A"),
          name3 = c('Pantoprazol', 'levothyroxine', 'nifedipine', 'Pantoprazol', 'Fusidinezuur', "Triamcinolonacetonide"),
           quantity3 = c(10, 10, 15, 30, 20, 10),
           dose3 = c(5, 5, 15, 0.5, 2, 10), 
           code3 = c('A', 'H', 'C', 'A', 'D', "S")
 )

code <- data.frame(med_name = c('Triamcinolonacetonide','Triamcinolonacetonide', 'nifedipine', 'Nystatine', 'Ethinylestradiol/​levonorgestrel', 'Pantoprazol', 'levothyroxine', 'Fusidinezuur'),
atc_code = c("D07AB09", "S02CA04", "C08CA05", "A07AA02", "G03AB03","A02BC02", "H03AA01", "D06AX01"),
first_code = c("D", "S", "C", "A", "G", "A", "H", "D"))

As there are several name and code columns (up to 77), I tried something like this:
data %>%
  select(grep("^code", names(data))) %>%
  mutate(case_when(. == code$med_name~ code$atc_code))

But this does not work, and does not link to code$first_code yet.
Also, this did not work:
for(i in 1:77){
  case_when(
    data[,paste0("data$code", i)] == code$name && data[,paste0("data$name", i)] == code$first_code ~ code$atc_code`)
    
}

Error: Error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate the left-hand side of formula 1.
Caused by error in `data[,paste0("data$code", i)] == code$name && data[,paste0("data$name", i)] == code$first_code ~ code$atc_code`:
! 'length = 152' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


You have data$code1, data$code2, data$code3. Which one exactly do you want to modify?

I'd suggest first reshaping longer to simplify things, since it looks like the name/quantity/dose/code data is functionally the same for each group of columns, only distinguished by "wave" --- so let's put "wave" in it's own column. That makes the lookup into a straightforward join, which is dramatically faster than any sort of row-by-row matching, simpler to read, and easier to maintain if the data structure were to change (ie this will work the same even if there are more waves).
Once joined with the replacement data, we can discard the old code column and reshape wider again.
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  # pivot longer so each grouping of columns is denoted by "wave"
  # alphabetical in one column, numbers in the other
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c(".value", "wave"), names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") |>

  # join to updated codes
  left_join(code, join_by(name == med_name, code == first_code)) |>
  
  # discard old "code" column and replace with atc_code
  select(ID:dose, code = atc_code) |>

  # reshape wide again
  pivot_wider(names_from = wave, names_sep = "", names_vary = "slowest",
              values_from = name:code)

Result
     ID name1                           quantity1 dose1 code1   name2                           quantity2 dose2 code2   name3                 quantity3 dose3 code3  
  <dbl> <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                               <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 Triamcinolonacetonide                  10   5   D07AB09 Pantoprazol                             5   0.1 A02BC02 Pantoprazol                  10   5   A02BC02
2     2 Triamcinolonacetonide                  10   5   S02CA04 levothyroxine                          10  15   H03AA01 levothyroxine                10   5   H03AA01
3     3 nifedipine                             15  15   C08CA05 Fusidinezuur                           10  15   D06AX01 nifedipine                   15  15   C08CA05
4     4 Nystatine                              30   0.5 A07AA02 Ethinylestradiol/levonorgestrel        20   7   G03AB03 Pantoprazol                  30   0.5 A02BC02
5     5 Ethinylestradiol/levonorgestrel        20   2   G03AB03 Nystatine                              20   5   A07AA02 Fusidinezuur                 20   2   D06AX01
6     6 Nystatine                              10  10   A07AA02 Nystatine                               5  12   A07AA02 Triamcinolonacetonide        10  10   S02CA04

